# Detect Gaps In VOB Video File

Tags: linux, video, vob

I have a single VOB video file running 2h 20m with 50 episodes of a TV show. There are no chapter markers or menu.

Can I use a Linux command line tool to detect the black screen between each episode and make an MP4 file from each 5 minute episode?

Here is the output from 'mediainfo'...

```
General
Complete name                            : Captain_Pugwash.vob
Format                                   : MPEG-PS
File size                                : 5.20 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 20mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 307 Kbps

Video
ID                                       : 224 (0xE0)
Format                                   : MPEG Video
Format version                           : Version 2
Format profile                           : Main@Main
Format settings, BVOP                    : Yes
Format settings, Matrix                  : Custom
Format settings, GOP                     : Variable
Format settings, picture structure       : Frame
Duration                                 : 2h 20mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 4 977 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 6 260 Kbps
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Standard                                 : PAL
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.480
Time code of first frame                 : 00:00:00:00
Time code source                         : Group of pictures header
GOP, Open/Closed                         : Open
GOP, Open/Closed of first frame          : Closed
Stream size                              : 4.88 GiB (94%)

Audio
ID                                       : 189 (0xBD)-128 (0x80)
Format                                   : AC-3
Format/Info                              : Audio Coding 3
Mode extension                           : CM (complete main)
Format settings, Endianness              : Big
Muxing mode                              : DVD-Video
Duration                                 : 2h 20mn
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 224 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 fps (1536 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 225 MiB (4%)
```

Thanks!

Paully

Comment: `ffmpeg`  has `blackframe` and `blackdetect` filters for this. You can have them [write frame metadata to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722747/can-you-put-the-result-of-a-blackdetect-filter-in-a-textfile-using-ffmpeg), and us these data in a second step to split the file (also with ffmpeg).